# Serving large Videofiles fails

Tags: http, go, go-echo

I'm using the Echo Framework's static filehandler for serving uploaded files out of my upload directory.

```
e := echo.New()
e.Static("/uploads","uploads")
```

This works fine for smaller video files. I've tested it with a 20MB videofile, which works fine. Larger files, for example a 50MB testfile, do not work. The underlying TCP connection gets closed before the whole file is being served.

Does anyone know if there is a filesize limit or a timer that can be set to prevent this?

Comment: You should look into streaming response https://echo.labstack.com/recipes/streaming-response

Comment: I do not think this is the right approach. For example, when using the http package, http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.FileServer(http.Dir("uploads"))) works fine, even with large files. I think there is either some limit that can be set within Echo, or it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `echo.File()`. This method serves, longer files, like yours because the underlying `net/http` package used in `http.FileServer()` and `echo.File()` are the same. You can add something like this

`echo.File("route","filepath",middleware)`.

You can also use the same functionality which is associated with `echo.Context` by the same name `c.File()`. Here the function definition is shorter and has an example in echo webpage https://echo.labstack.com/cookbook/file-download.